# Too high resolution!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I kind of messed up. I went to Minecraft today and looked through the video settings. I put the resolution all the way up and my computer couldn't handle it. If this has happened to any of you please help me?

Comment: So can your computer handle it enough to at least reopen the video settings and change it back? If not I bet uninstalling the game and reinstalling would fix it. That should (I would think) delete any settings file on your machine and reinstall the default one.

Comment: What do you mean with "can't handle it"? Did Minecraft crash? Did the computer burst into changes? Did it tell you how it can't handle the stress anymore? Also, what do you mean with "resolution"? The fullscreen resolution? That would be capped at your screen resolution.

Comment: So are you trying to upscale your resolution to your native resolution so that the game isn't laggy?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're asking how to reset the video options: go to your *[.minecraft](https://minecraft.wiki/w/.minecraft)* folder and delete '[Options.txt](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Options.txt)'. This file contains your (customized) settings. Deleting it will reset everything (including your controls).

Comment: Thank you! It helped, but I have to reset my controls which is kind of annoying but I'll live!

Comment: Glad it did! Can you select this as the right answer?